# Nginx container always gives 404

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, kubernetes

Please look at below `nginx.conf` content which is present in my azure aks:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/secrets/default;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/secrets/default;

    server_name _;
    server_tokens "on";
    access_log off;



    location / {
       return 404;
    }
}

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

looking at the above content i figured out that my ingress contents are present in conf.d folder.

If we see, location / is present before my other configurations. does that mean it is always returning 404 because of this reason?

Comment: Any suggestions please. I want to know if this is the case and if so, how do we resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `location` setting lets you configure how nginx will respond to requests for resources within the server.

> You can have more than one location directive.

Request: http://example.com/

Returns: Assuming that there is a `server_name` entry for `example.com`, the `location /` directive will determine what happens with this request. In your case, it will `return 404`. And since every request can map to `location /`, nginx will always respond with 404.

Refer https://linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx/#location-file-and-folder-configuration for more info.

What you have here is the conf for default backend. The default backend is a service which handles all url paths. It returns a 404 when the Ingress Controller cannot successfully route a request according to the mapping rules.

`location /` being present before (as in the order of occurrences) other configurations is not the problem here.

The `default-http-backend` is not designed to be outside facing -- it is merely designed to 404 so the Ingress controller can universally `/dev/null` traffic for Pod-less Services.

Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough

Comment: I am aware of this. But i need to know why `location / ` is appearing first in the conf file from kubernetes deployment perspective not in general as a nginx software. So please guide  me from Kubernetes containers perspective